# What is the way to know the number of rows a Postgres INDEX currently manages?

Tags: postgresql, index

In Postgres, I created an index which looks like this:

```
CREATE INDEX foo_idx ON foo (other_id)
 WHERE a = 1 AND b = 2 AND c = 3 AND other_id IS NOT NULL;
```

Now I'd like to know how many of the 150,000 or so rows were indexed in that specific index. I saw the `pg_indexes_size()` and `pq_table_size()`, but that gives us the size of the file, not the number of rows.

What is the way to know the number of rows currently managed by `foo_idx`?

I can, of course, use a `SELECT`, but that means I could have an incorrect `WHERE` clause if the index changed.

Comment: [pageinspect](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pageinspect.html) might be useful

Comment: I'd say a query is the only reasonable way.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I checked that page and it's very specialized... Also it looks like for B-Tree there isn't one entry with the total number. Only entries for each page managed in the B-Tree: `bt_page_stats.live_items`.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at pg_class.reltuples, but those numbers are estimates based on the most recent vacuum/analyze, so are neither perfectly up-to-date nor perfectly accurate.

> I could have an incorrect WHERE clause if the index changed.

Indexes are not editable in that way.  For the WHERE to change, you would need to drop the index and create a new one.

Comment: Right. We have some SQL scripts that are run to upgrade our schema. That may do a `DROP` + `CREATE` of an index and the `WHERE` clause could end up changing... and there is indeed no [`ALTER INDEX` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-alterindex.html) that would change the `WHERE`.